# Typescript Unions based on property inside nested object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I'm trying to create a Union Type based on a nested property in my object. See the example below:

```ts
type Foo = {
    abilities: {
        canManage: boolean
    }
}

type Bar = {
    abilities: {
        canManage: boolean
    }
    extraProp: number
}

type Condition1 = {
    abilities: {
        canManage: true
    }
} & Bar

type Condition2 = {
    abilities: {
        canManage: false
    }
} & Foo

type TotalData = Condition1 | Condition2

const data: TotalData = {
    abilities: {
        canManage: false, // if canManage is false, TS should complain when I add the `extraProp` key
    },
    extraProp: 5
}
```

The issue I'm having is that typescript ignores the conditions I set. I'm interested in only allowing certain properties if the canMange value is true. This doesn't seem to work when it's nested. But if I had simply something like this without nesting, it would be fine:

```js
type Foo = {
     canManage: boolean
}

type Bar = {
    canManage: boolean
    extraProp: number
}

type Condition1 = {
    canManage: true
} & Bar

type Condition2 = {
    canManage: false
} & Foo
]
type TotalData = Condition1 | Condition2

const data: TotalData = {

canManage: false,
extraProp: 5 // now typescript complains that this property shouldn't be here because canManage is false
}
```

How can I go about solving this issue when trying to set a Union based on the property inside a nested object?

Comment: Would `type Foo = { abilities: { canManage: boolean }; extraProp?: never }` meet your needs?  Extra properties are only prohibited in specific circumstances and this doesn't seem to be one of them.  If that works for you I'll write up an answer; if not, please explain what doesn't work for your use case.  Good luck!

Comment: That solution may work for the time being, but it's a little hacky and since this is a real problem with TypeScript you should probably submit a bug report.

Comment: 4.2 might solve this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/38839

Comment: unfortunately, [nope](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/38839#issuecomment-1160929515)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The compiler doesn't understand the concept of "nested discriminated unions". A type is a discriminated union if the members of the union share a common "discriminant" property.  A discriminant property is generally a singleton/literal type like `true` or `"hello"` or `123` or even `null` or `undefined`.  You *can't* use another discriminated union as a discriminant itself, though. It would be nice if you could, because then discriminated unions could propagate up from nested properties the way you're doing.  There's a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758) to allow this, but I don't see any movement there.

As it stands, the type `TotalData` isn't a *discriminated* union.  It's just a union.  That means the compiler will not try to treat a value of type `TotalData` as   *exclusively* either `Condition1` or `Condition2`.  So you will probably run into issues if you write code that tests `data.abilities.canManage` and expects the compiler to understand the implications:

```
function hmm(x: TotalData) {
    if (x.abilities.canManage) {
        x.extraProp.toFixed(); // error!
    //  ~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- possibly undefined?!
    } 
}
```

If you want to do this you might find yourself needing to write [user-defined type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) instead:

```
function isCondition1(x: TotalData): x is Condition1 {
    return x.abilities.canManage;
}

function hmm(x: TotalData) {
    if (isCondition1(x)) {
        x.extraProp.toFixed(); // okay!
    } 
}
```

---

The specific issue you're running into here, where `data` is seen as a valid `TotalData` has to do with how [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) is performed.  Object types in TypeScript are "open"/"extendable", not "closed"/"[exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)". You are allowed to add extra properties unmentioned in a type's definition without violating the type.  So the compiler can't prohibit excess properties completely; instead, it uses heuristics to try to figure out when such properties are a mistake and when they are intentional.  The rule used is mostly: if you are creating a brand new object literal and any of its properties are not mentioned in the type of where it's being used, there will be an error.  Otherwise there won't be.

If `TotalData` were a discriminated union, you'd get the error you expect on `data` because `data.abilities.canManage` would cause the compiler to narrow `data` from `TotalData` to `Condition2` which doesn't mention `extraProp`.  But it's not, and so `data` remains `TotalData` which *does* mention `extraProp`.

It's been proposed, in [microsoft/TypeScript#20863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863), that excess property checking be stricter for non-discriminated unions.  I pretty much agree; mixing and matching properties from different union members doesn't seem to be a common use case, so a warning would probably be helpful.  But again, this is a longstanding issue and I don't see any movement there.

---

One thing you can do for this is to be more explicit about excess properties you'd like to guard against.  A value of type `{a: string}` can have a `b` property of type `string`, but a value of type `{a: string, b?: never}` cannot.  So this latter type will prevent properties of type `b` without relying on the compiler's heuristics for excess property checking.

In your case:

```
type Foo = {
    abilities: {
        canManage: boolean
    };
    extraProp?: never
}
```

will behave very similarly to your original `Foo` definition, but now you get this error:

```
const data: TotalData = { // error!
// -> ~~~~
// Type '{ abilities: { canManage: false; }; extraProp: number; }'
// is not assignable to type 'TotalData'.
    abilities: {
        canManage: false,
    },
    extraProp: 5
}
```

The compiler can no longer reconcile `data` with either `Condition1` or `Condition2`, so it complains.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-yqnwI32NSggwFMSh98h1BoiOtNCQkHndnu9UCcNmDodh8JwEdokgIBygwezdM2FDzsRZdeN9CzWT5uR1wDgMAI8gg1UDEc5WKMqIx9CxhOJq+JUAAPNjt1AwHBZQQlSAoOZqhADgQ9NUtIvsOMIOzttF+w7+WBZ7J53AlKNPPRG82rj+omzBBvIEY9pIfY6gOjpgMOo7jpO04fpKiBfj+6RyI+vbYC+2RvqhGG-h4QA)

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth reply! Really helped me understand what's going on, I really appreciate it

Comment: This might get solved in 4.2! https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/38839

Comment: unfortunately, [nope](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/38839#issuecomment-1160929515)