# TypeScript Nested inference and Narrowing

Tags: typescript, type-inference, narrowing

I'm working on a typed API and I've run into an issue trying to discriminate between a request and response pair.

Here's a simple example:

```
// method, input and output types all inferred from elsewhere and **always** exist
const { req, res } = {} as
    | {
            req: { method: "GET"; input: number };
            res: { output: string };
        }
    | {
            req: { method: "POST"; input: boolean };
            res: { output: number };
        };

if (req.method === "GET") {
    // Can infer ctx.req.input because method is a property of ctx.req
    const input = req.input;
    // Won't infer ctx.res.output because method is not a property of ctx.res
    const output = res.output;
}
```

So, logically speaking, the type of `ctx.req.output` should be inferred by inspecting `ctx.res.method`, but this is not how TypeScript works it seems (documentation would be helpful) since `ctx.res.output` remains as `string | number` instead of being narrowed to `string`.

Any suggestions?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFsFMBcAsHsAmAaUBLAdgBwK7VAIYaKjx677QCeWkAzoQDaPoYBmkATp5CW5-HChIjOpADusLpELFQAKnkFG4glTqLhADzR1oAKADG8DHtABvUDwCOqHgwC+oALwWnBOvtDfQAHwtePkFBNgBcFhAwCIjhAEQA4gCiACqxANysFOEYOOAARlygDmmBwcH24ZZk0FmgepyYAOZFJWXeDqV+AW3lkNaVkXBIcQAKAPIAyqkZmLV58PCMkEQtnT0VEdW1OfmFxWs++-pobKAAFDYAdFBDJM73oAkpsQCU3T4goADCK5gcnKBDNAtJcrrM8KACoYCDgxINougGARQFgBLRONRSKcgSCbJ1jKZ8OD8K4wdg8K0PmAAOomADkRPYhRxoPoly2EKhMLhNwRulAGHg+GRqPg6Mx8GxwNZniCBLMHJJVjZipKDiAA)

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61732108/typescript-unions-based-on-property-inside-nested-object)? See also this [PR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61732108/typescript-unions-based-on-property-inside-nested-object) that was ultimately decided against.